# Core Image vector comparison bug?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, core-image

According to the GLSLangSpec, the `==` & `!=` operators for vectors consider 2 vectors equal if all corresponding components are equal.  The Core Image Kernel Language specification doesn't mention any deviation from this in it's changes from GLSL.  But when I do such a compare within a Core Image Filter in Quartz Composer, it clearly only compares the 1st (red) component.  Is this a known bug?

This is under OSX 10.6.8.  Does it perhaps work correctly in later versions?  Or will I just have to use my own custom comparison function?